# The LightningMessageChannel named boatMessageChannel was not found in the workspace

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

In LWC Super badge Challenge 2, we have to create a lightning message channel named BoatMessageChannel.

I tried creating it with the name boatMessageChannel coz the naming should be in the camel case.

But while verifying the channel I'm not able to complete the challenge though I have verified that the channel is properly deployed by including it into lwc.

After searching a while I found that I have to use **BoatMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml** rather than **boatMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml**. but while deploying this file I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lightning Message Channel should be in the camel case is the best practice.

But in challenge 2, they are applying the test case which checks the LMC with Pascal case, and hence it fails to complete.

**Note:** while deploying from the file editor context we are getting the mentioned error that

> SourceElementDoesNotExist: The LightningMessageChannel named boatMessageChannel was not found in the workspace.

To deploy it, we have to right-click on the file from the file explorer which will not give the error mentioned above.